# Creating a database in MySQL using node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm following a tutorial that requires me to create a database, normally i would have created this through phpmyadmin but i obviously can't do this. The following is the script required, i've tried the create line on my command line but it doesn't seem to work. Where do i run the database script? I'm using npm, and using my windows command line

```
create database test;

use test;

CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  age int(3) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

you dont have to specify database to connect to server.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  multipleStatements: true // this allow you to run multiple queries at once.
});

var sqlCommand = `
create database test;

use test;

CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  age int(3) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
`
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected yet no db is selected yet!");
  con.query("CREATE DATABASE users", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database created");
  });
// OR allow multiple queries in createConnection and run
// con.query(sqlCommand, function (err, result) {
//    if (err) throw err;
//    console.log("Database created");
//  });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

it can be done using nodejs file, follow this code to create database in mysql

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "dbname"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "CREATE TABLE users (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255), email VARCHAR(255))";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Table created");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thankyou, i'm following the tutorial at http://blog.chapagain.com.np/node-js-express-mysql-simple-add-edit-delete-view-crud/

Step 12 runs the create database line, it would seem like he uses the command line, is this the case?

Comment: I think he missed that part to include in js file, you can add this table creation part there

Comment: How is that supposed to create database when you're specifying 'database' in your config file? You simply will receive Unknown database 'dbname'.